# How and why does Express uses MVC pattern?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I've tried to the net to understand why Express uses MVC to structure the code, but I haven't really got any explanation. Can anyone please describe how Express can be used to structure codes that follows the MVC design pattern?

Comment: Express is just a framework to run your web server on top of node.js. It's up to you as the owner of the application if you wish to structure your code in Mode, Controller manner. you could have everything in one single file and everything would work as expected.

Comment: I understand that it will be possbile on a single file, but when creating a scaffolding and as i have seen in many examples, they usually use MVC styles.

Comment: And if they use MVC style, they'd get MVC application. That's how MVC works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple.

You just modularize your code in different modules and folders and import/export with commonJS (`require` as `import/export` isn't yet that popular in Node).

You can create a `model` folder where you can place all of your schema declarations, a `controller` folder where you'd place all of your logics to handle the routes, a `route` folder where you'd place all of your routes (thanks to `express router`) and a `views` folder where you'd place all of your `pug`, `ejs` etc. files (if you'd like to make a server-side rendered app).

All the client-side code and static files usually go into a `public` folder and voilà, here is your MVC structure with Express.

Comment: He is asking for the "why", your are explaining the "how". His question is wrong at first in my opinion, as he doesn't grasp the concept well.

Comment: It's partially true. After he asks this: "Can anyone please describe how Express can be used to structure codes that follows the MVC design pattern?"

Comment: Thanks @Mattia for the well explaination. That is what I exactly needed to understand how these different pieces can fit into a MVC. Though, the other part is the 'Why'. If I am not wrong, it's must be because MVC can be a good choice here as these different files can be structured within these directories.

Comment: well, as the question's titles goes, I mentioned how and why ;-)

Comment: Yes correct, it's much more readable in an MVC structure, despite it's not the only way of doing it. After you touch even a little bit your code, it becomes completely unmanageable. I ususally make an MVC structure even to simulate little code problems!

Answer (score 0):

**Why use MVC?**

We use MVC for numerous reasons but some of them are:

- easily understandable structure which makes code easier to write, maintain, and collaborate on
- follows the clean code rule of "separation of concerns"
- the loose coupling between sections means that the different aspects (model, view, controller) can be worked on independently
- code reusability
- changing the view does not affect the model
- easier to divide the front end from the back end
- easier to test: naturally embraces test driven development

**How does Express fit in to all of this?**

- Express is used for routing via the express Router class. Express also makes it very easy to build an initial MVC structure via the Express App Generator

**In the MVC pattern we have 3 concepts:**

- *view:* this is what end users see and interact with. Views are structured from templates and these templates are ultimately populated by the results from controller logic interacting with the model.
- *model:* this is our interface for interacting with the database using our programming language of choice. The model determines how the database and its documents are structured. Document structure is ultimately decided by the Schema. Your Schema is compiled into a model. This model can then be used by the controller as an interface for interacting with the db.
- the controller is the "brains" or "business logic" within the MVC pattern. It interacts with the model when user requests are made. The controller chosen for the task is dependent on the Router -- **this is where Express comes in - it handles our routing by matching HTTP verbs with URL patterns and sends the request to the correct controller**. Note that while its not directly included in the acronym "MVC" its common place to put your routers (i.e your instances of the Express Router class) in their own directory to then be imported where needed.

*to clarify further:*
Let's look at the MVC pattern as if its a restaurant:

- the ***view*** is the customer - it makes requests to the ***controller*** which in this scenario behaves as a waiter. The waiter then takes the customer's request and *handles it* by passing it to the ***model*** which here could be considered the kitchen. The kitchen (model) in turn uses the resources available to it (like our database) to fulfill the customers request. When the food is ready (i.e when the request result is ready) the waiter (our controller) brings the food (or result of the request) back to the customer and presents them with their food (the result, usually HTML).